# How to get text value from a VuetifyJS combobox?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've never used the combobox before so maybe I'm just not understanding the use case. How do I get the user inputted value versus getting the selected value on button press? Here's a contrived codepen: https://codepen.io/tmpjr/pen/JjjxjGR It only seems to work with getting a selected option. When I enter text I just get null or undefined.

https://codepen.io/tmpjr/pen/JjjxjGR

```
<!--- Template --->
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="4">
          <v-combobox
            v-model="course"
            :items="items"
            item-value="id"
            item-text="text"
            :return-object="true"
            label="Select a favorite golf course"
            outlined
            clearable
          >
            <template v-slot:append-outer>
              <v-btn small fab dark color="primary">
                <v-icon dark @click="saveItem">check</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
          </v-combobox>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
// JavaScript
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      course: null,
      items: [
        { id: 1, text: "The Bridges" },
         { id: 2, text: "Morgan Run" },

      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveItem() {
      console.log("saveItem");
      console.log(this.course);
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug as the v-model appears to only update when the combobox loses focus. I've submitted a bug to VuetifyJS.

Comment: Since the bug is still open and labelled as "help wanted" I will comment here in case someone else runs into this again. This works much better for me, than the accepted answer: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4679#issuecomment-773459937

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a bug report and it was marked as a duplicate of:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4679#issuecomment-469009775

where I found the following workaround:

**@input.native="course=$event.srcElement.value"**

```
<v-combobox
  v-model="course"
  :items="items"
  item-value="id"
  item-text="text"
  :return-object="true"
  label="Select a favorite golf course"
  outlined
  clearable
  @input.native="course=$event.srcElement.value"
>
  <template v-slot:append-outer>
    <v-btn small fab dark color="primary">
      <v-icon dark @click="saveItem">check</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </template>
</v-combobox>
```

https://codepen.io/tmpjr/pen/rNNRVGq

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `blur`or `change`event of the [combobox](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox) component.

Then you can assign a method to the event and if combobox loses focus, the method gets called:

```js
<combobox
  @change="onChange"
/>

<script>
  methods: {
    onChange(value) {
      //here you have access to the text the user has typed into textfield of combobox
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did check into this and it does not work. The only thing that works is when the combobox loses focus then the v-model is updated. I've created a bug report with the VuetifyJS devs.